# Why doesn't Luke's lightsaber cut Jabba's guards in Episode 6?

Tags: star-wars

In *Return of the Jedi* when Luke is taken to the Dune Sea to be cast into the Pit of Carkoon why is it that when he strikes Jabba the Hutt’s guards with his lightsaber they are merely knocked off the desert skiff and not cut? The sound of the lightsaber striking an object is clearly heard.

This is the snippet from *Return of the Jedi* where the lightsaber strike knocks the target away:

[image]

While a similar strike in Phantom Menance cuts cleanly through the target

> spoiler: only click if you've seen episode 1 https://imgflip.com/gif/kazbz

Comment: clearly, luke was just psyching him out with the lightsaber swing, and then he uses a force push to knock him over.

Comment: Probably because Luke's lightsaber was a little dull after being stored in R2 for so long.

Comment: @phantom42 Actually, that seems plausible, considering some [other moves](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_kick) he uses in the battle.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**It's assumed that the lightsaber cut the guard's flesh, but the wound does not appear onscreen.**

The original trilogy goes out of its way to avoid showing realistic gore or wounds. Unlike films of today, a PG rating 30 years ago allowed very little blood or visible wounds. At the time, the dismembered arm in [Episode IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_(film)) and the Tauntaun intestines of [Episode V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Empire_Strikes_Back) were pushing the boundaries of what was allowed in a PG film.

Although it is never shown directly, we can assume that the lightsaber was meant to be cutting into the guards just like we would expect. The films use a combination of distance shots & fast cutaways to avoid showing anything that would affect the film's rating. In the example you give, the guard could very well have a huge gaping slash across his mid-section, but we never see that part of his body as he falls back and down into the pit.

Comment: This might also be another way that Lucas "tributes" older movies. Consider, for example, some of Kurosawa's samurai films. There's no blood and gore, just someone gets hit with a sword, and falls over.

Comment: @KSmarts very true. Same thing for westerns - gun goes off, then guy grabs his belly or head and falls over. No special effects needed, the audience's imagination fills in the blanks.

Comment: But how does the lightsaber exert that much force to push him off the skiff? In the "cutting" example, the lightsaber doesn't exert force on Maul, it just slices. Following similar rules Maul shouldn't have stayed in place as the slice happened, but should have fallen over to the side.

Comment: @Esaevian Wouldn't you be reeling backwards and off balance by your own attempt at evasion if someone started swinging a lightsaber at you? :)

Comment: @Esaevian not sure I understand - when Maul was cut in half, he also fell backwards and into the pit (immediately after the OP's gif cuts out). In fact, every case I can think of where someone gets slashed with a lightsaber, they fall back and away from the blade.

Comment: It's ok.  He got better.

Comment: Question is also how good it would have looked back then. Nowadays computers are used to help out in scenes where one is cut in half.....back then I don't think so

Comment: @Omegacron The difference is that it seems that Luke's saber is transferring the force of his swing to the guy that falls. Note how Luke's swing stops as soon as the saber makes contact. Maul's fall wasn't caused by the force of Obi-Wan's swing, but just by the fact that he no longer could keep his balance since he was dead/dying.

Comment: @Doresoom That makes sense, but the fact that Luke's saber seems to be transferring force from Luke's swing into the guy that falls tells me that the guy was pushed, rather than him trying to evade.